# How to separate the corresponding column value in the scriptdb query statement in google apps script

Tags: database, google-apps-script, clouddb

While I'm retrieving the values from the scriptdb it returns the entire db while using the below coding.

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var result = db.query({});
```

While using the following coding it retrieves the corresponding row fully which satisfies the condition.

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var result = db.query({p_cost:324});
```

I want to get the specified column value in the specified row which I retrieved already by using the above coding. Is there any possibility to get the specified column value from the scriptdb? We are write the query in traditional database as follows.

```
SELECE <COL_NAME> FROM <TABLE_NAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while(result.hasnext()){ 

  res = result.next();
  var p_cost = res.p_cost;

}
```